# CSS3 -ms-max-content in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

We can set in CSS3 `-moz-max-content` (for Firefox) and `-webkit-max-content` (for Chrome, Safari) as `width`, but it seems `-ms-max-content` is not working in Internet Explorer (IE11).

**Update:** Here is a sample code:

```css
.button {
    background: #d1d1d1;
    margin: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;    
    width: -moz-max-content;
    width: -webkit-max-content;
    width: -o-max-content;
    width: -ms-max-content;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="button"> Short t. </div>
    <div class="button"> Looooooong text </div>
    <div class="button"> Medium text </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: maybe some code would be good so people could help you.

Comment: Question updated with code example. Thanks.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`-max-content` it is not supported by IE, according to [CanIuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=intrinsic-width).

So I created a fallback for IE that might help you, by setting `.button` to `display:inline-block`:

```css
.button {
  background: #d1d1d1;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  width: -o-max-content;
  /* width: -ms-max-content;*/
}


/* fallback for IE*/

.button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="button">Short t.</div>
  <div class="button">Looooooong text</div>
  <div class="button">Medium text</div>
</div>
```

---

**UPDATE: (Based on OP comment)**

> It's working, but I don't want to display the elements inline.

here is the final answer:

```css
.button {
  background: #d1d1d1;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: -moz-max-content;
  width: -webkit-max-content;
  width: -o-max-content
  /* width: -ms-max-content;*/
}
/* fallback for IE*/
.width {
  width:100%
}
.button {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="width">
    <div class="button">Short t.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="width">
    <div class="button">Looooooong text</div>
  </div>
  <div class="width">
    <div class="button">Medium text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

### NEW UPDATE

Nowadays and for awhile there is a cleaner approach to this issue, by simply setting the parent as `display: flex`, and you even won't need the `*-max-content` value in `width` property

```css
.button {
  background: #d1d1d1;
  margin: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* the fix */

section {
  display: flex
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="button">Short t.</div>
  <div class="button">Looooooong text</div>
  <div class="button">Medium text</div>
</section>
```

Comment: What if the content is already inline and the content is displayed at varying heights?

Comment: please provide a fiddle

Comment: The idea is to get the div to fit the content inside instead of extending to the max size. You still need the max-content to do that even with a flexbox.

https://jsfiddle.net/k7643o5d/3/

Comment: for that you need to add `align-items: flex-start` in parent because by default it is `align-items: stretch`

Answer (score 39):

This works on IE11, Chrome and Firefox

instead of

```
width: -moz-max-content;
width: -webkit-max-content;
width: -o-max-content;
width: -ms-max-content;
```

I used

```
width: auto;
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: This saved the day. I was having trouble with max-content in Safari. This solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For text elements I tried `word-break: keep-all;` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Work for flex div.
I use to change the height of the parent.

```
.div-parent {
  display:-webkit-inline-box;
  display:-ms-inline-flexbox;
  display:inline-flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: -70px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left:20px;
  height: 70px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.div-children{
  display:block;
  padding-left:15px;
  padding-right:15px;
  padding-top:0px;
  padding-bottom:0px;
  width: 100%;
}

$("<div class='div-children'>Content...</>").appendTo(".div-parent");
var hd=70; 
while($('.div-parent')[0].scrollHeight > $('.div-parent')[0].clientHeight){
    hd=hd+1;
    $('.div-parent').css("height",hd+"px");
}   
$('.div-parent').css("top","0");
$('.div-parent').css("opacity","1");
```