# Absolute flexbox container's width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How to get an absolute-positioned flex container to take the correct width based on its content? I've spent hours with [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/h8rLmtz6/) but haven't been able to figure out what the problem is. This is what I've ended up with:

[image]

Code from the example:

```css
.container {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: white;
}

.nav {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  min-height: 3.57143rem;
}

.nav__root {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.nav__root ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav__root li {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.0;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.nav__root li a {
  color: #777;
}

.nav__root li a:hover {
  color: #333;
}

.nav__dropdown {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.nav__toggle {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1.07143rem;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.nav__menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 14.28571rem;
  padding: 0.35714rem 0;
  margin: 0.14286rem 0 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.nav__submenu {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 1.07143rem;
  margin-left: 1.07143rem;
}

.nav__separator {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.nav-level--1>li>a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="nav">
    <ul class="nav__root">
      <li class="first nav__dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
          <strong>Foo</strong>
          <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav__menu">
          <li class="first">
            <a href="#">Foo</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Bar</a>
          </li>
          <li class="last">
            <a href="#">Baz</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav__dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
          <strong>Bar</strong>
          <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav__menu">
          <li class="first nav__submenu">
            <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
              <strong>Foo</strong>
              <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav-level--2">
              <li class="first">
                <a href="#">Foo Foo Foo Foo </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Bar Bar Bar Bar </a>
              </li>
              <li class="last">
                <a href="#">Baz Baz Baz Baz </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__submenu">
            <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
              <strong>Bar</strong>
              <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav-level--2">
              <li class="first">
                <a href="#">Foo Foo Foo Foo </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Bar Bar Bar Bar </a>
              </li>
              <li class="last">
                <a href="#">Baz Baz Baz Baz </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="last nav__submenu">
            <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
              <strong>Baz</strong>
              <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav-level--2">
              <li class="first">
                <a href="#">Foo Foo Foo Foo </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Bar Bar Bar Bar </a>
              </li>
              <li class="last">
                <a href="#">Baz Baz Baz Baz </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="last nav__dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
          <strong>Baz</strong>
          <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>
        <ul class="nav__menu">
          <li class="first nav__submenu">
            <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
              <strong>Foo</strong>
              <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav-level--2">
              <li class="first">
                <a href="#">Foo Foo Foo Foo </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Bar Bar Bar Bar </a>
              </li>
              <li class="last">
                <a href="#">Baz Baz Baz Baz </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav__submenu">
            <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
              <strong>Bar</strong>
              <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav-level--2">
              <li class="first">
                <a href="#">Foo Foo Foo Foo </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Bar Bar Bar Bar </a>
              </li>
              <li class="last">
                <a href="#">Baz Baz Baz Baz </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="last nav__submenu">
            <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
              <strong>Baz</strong>
              <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="nav-level--2">
              <li class="first">
                <a href="#">Foo Foo Foo Foo </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#">Bar Bar Bar Bar </a>
              </li>
              <li class="last">
                <a href="#">Baz Baz Baz Baz </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Comment: In the future please add your code to the question itself. I've done it for you this time. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Paulie_D sorry guys I thought the code was too long to put it right here.

Comment: That's why we ask for a **minimal** demo. We don't need the whole codebase, just enough to show the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem this way: the backend renderer generates classes like `nav__menu--1`, `nav__menu--2` and so on depending on the number of columns in a menu. On the other end SASS generates particular widths for every class based on the width of one menu column:

```
$menu-column-width: rem-calc(200px);

@for $i from 1 through 6 {
  .nav__menu--#{$i} {
    width: $menu-column-width * $i;
  }
}
```

So I've ended up with hardcoded widths which works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem:

The **containing block** of an absolutely-positioned element is the nearest positioned ancestor.

In this case, that means that the width of your drop-down menus (`position: absolute`) are confined to the width of the main nav items (`position: relative`).

So, for the drop-downs to expand beyond their containing blocks, you will either (1) need to remove the positioning from the nav items and place it at a higher level, such as the nav bar. But this can get messy. You'll need to re-position all absolutely positioned drop-downs; (2) add width to the main nav items; (3) try a different method.

More about CSS positioning: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Answer (score 1):

> `width:max-content`, give this property to your class `nav__menu`

This will work perfect for you.

```css
.container {
  padding-right: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
  max-width: 1170px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  background: white;
}

.nav {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  min-height: 3.57143rem;
}

.nav__root {
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.nav__root ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav__root li {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.0;
  color: #777;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.nav__root li a {
  color: #777;
}

.nav__root li a:hover {
  color: #333;
}

.nav__dropdown {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.nav__toggle {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 1.07143rem;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.nav__menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  width: max-content;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 14.28571rem;
  padding: 0.35714rem 0;
  margin: 0.14286rem 0 0;
  font-size: 1rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
  box-shadow: 0 6px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.175);
  background-clip: padding-box;
}

.nav__submenu {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: auto;
  margin-right: 1.07143rem;
  margin-left: 1.07143rem;
}

.nav__separator {
  height: 1px;
  margin: 9px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
}

.nav-level--1>li>a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="nav">

    <ul class="nav__root">

      <li class="first nav__dropdown">

        <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
          <strong>Foo</strong>
          <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>

        <ul class="nav__menu">

          <li class="first">

            <a href="#">Foo</a>

          </li>

          <li>

            <a href="#">Bar</a>

          </li>

          <li class="last">

            <a href="#">Baz</a>

          </li>

        </ul>

      </li>

      <li class="nav__dropdown">

        <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
          <strong>Bar</strong>
          <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>

        <ul class="nav__menu">

          <li class="first nav__submenu">

            <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
              <strong>Foo</strong>
              <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>

            <ul class="nav-level--2">

              <li class="first">

                <a href="#">Foo Foo Foo Foo </a>

              </li>

              <li>

                <a href="#">Bar Bar Bar Bar </a>

              </li>

              <li class="last">

                <a href="#">Baz Baz Baz Baz </a>

              </li>

            </ul>

          </li>

          <li class="nav__submenu">

            <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
              <strong>Bar</strong>
              <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>

            <ul class="nav-level--2">

              <li class="first">

                <a href="#">Foo Foo Foo Foo </a>

              </li>

              <li>

                <a href="#">Bar Bar Bar Bar </a>

              </li>

              <li class="last">

                <a href="#">Baz Baz Baz Baz </a>

              </li>

            </ul>

          </li>

          <li class="last nav__submenu">

            <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
              <strong>Baz</strong>
              <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>

            <ul class="nav-level--2">

              <li class="first">

                <a href="#">Foo Foo Foo Foo </a>

              </li>

              <li>

                <a href="#">Bar Bar Bar Bar </a>

              </li>

              <li class="last">

                <a href="#">Baz Baz Baz Baz </a>

              </li>

            </ul>

          </li>

        </ul>

      </li>

      <li class="last nav__dropdown">

        <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
          <strong>Baz</strong>
          <b class="caret"></b>
        </a>

        <ul class="nav__menu">

          <li class="first nav__submenu">

            <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
              <strong>Foo</strong>
              <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>

            <ul class="nav-level--2">

              <li class="first">

                <a href="#">Foo Foo Foo Foo </a>

              </li>

              <li>

                <a href="#">Bar Bar Bar Bar </a>

              </li>

              <li class="last">

                <a href="#">Baz Baz Baz Baz </a>

              </li>

            </ul>

          </li>

          <li class="nav__submenu">

            <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
              <strong>Bar</strong>
              <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>

            <ul class="nav-level--2">

              <li class="first">

                <a href="#">Foo Foo Foo Foo </a>

              </li>

              <li>

                <a href="#">Bar Bar Bar Bar </a>

              </li>

              <li class="last">

                <a href="#">Baz Baz Baz Baz </a>

              </li>

            </ul>

          </li>

          <li class="last nav__submenu">

            <a href="#" class="nav__toggle">
              <strong>Baz</strong>
              <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>

            <ul class="nav-level--2">

              <li class="first">

                <a href="#">Foo Foo Foo Foo </a>

              </li>

              <li>

                <a href="#">Bar Bar Bar Bar </a>

              </li>

              <li class="last">

                <a href="#">Baz Baz Baz Baz </a>

              </li>

            </ul>

          </li>

        </ul>

      </li>

    </ul>

  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: My bad, I didn't pay attention to that edit. It's fixed now.

Comment: Well then, [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22835556/7427111) is the workaround.