# Browser compatibility issue with CSS3 for the values of 'max-content' and 'fit-content' for the WIDTH attribute

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, microsoft-edge

The values for the Width attribute 'max-content' and 'fit-content' is not working on Edge, and Internet Explorer.

---

```
 .div{
    border: 1px solid;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: max-content;
    width: -moz-max-content; //works fine on Mozilla
    width: -ms-max-content; //doesn't work on EDGE and MS-Explorer

}
```

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#search=max-content - What's your point?

Answer (score 0):

you could see from the link in the comment that both max-content and fit-content are not supported by IE and Edge.

I suggest that maybe there is a workaround that using display:inline-block. Since not knowing how is your page designed, I just make a test on my side. Hope this will be helpful.

CSS.

```
    <style>
    .box {
        background-color: #f0f3f9;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 10px auto 20px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .inline-block {
        display: inline-block;
    }

</style>
```

HTML.

```
    <strong>display:inline-block;</strong>
    <div class="box inline-block">
      <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/200x200.jpg">
      <p>What a lovely pattern we got there in this image which is encapsulted in a figure.</p>
   </div>
```

Besides, you could also refer to this link:[CSS3 -ms-max-content in IE11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22834379/css3-ms-max-content-in-ie11)